# Расположение элементов в футере

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разместить параграф, img, ссылки как на картинке используя flexbox

Comment: Ну разместите. А в чем проблема?

Comment: извините, но если бы не было проблемы, не писал сюда

Comment: ну, вам человек написал "в чем проблема"... Вы написали, что она есть, но мы, к сожалению ее не видим. Вы тут просто кинули "ану решили мне задачку", не дав даже строчки кода, который вы попробовали применить... Поэтому тут проблемы у вас нету, вам просто нужно по-бырику решить задачу.

Comment: Даже если так, это трудно сделать? Человек без лишних вопросов, дал решение и все. Спасибо ему за это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

justify-content: space-between;

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
.child{
  background-color: green;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Left text</div>
  <div class="child">Middle logo</div>
  <div class="child ">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Не догадался ссылки разместить в одном блоке